# Clearing my form inputs after submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried it a few different ways based on searches I've done on the subject and for some reason I can't get it to work. I just want my text inputs and textarea to clear after I hit the submit button.

Here's the code.

```
<div id="sidebar-info">
    <form name="contact-form" action="formprocess.php" method="post" target="ninja-frame">
        <h1>By Phone</h1>
        <p id="by-phone">XXX-XXX-XXXX</p>
        <h1>By Email</h1>
        <p id="form-row">Name</p>
        <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="user-input" value="">
        <p id="form-row">Email</p>
        <input name="email" id="email" type="text" class="user-input" value="">
        <p id="form-row">Message</p>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" class="user-input" rows="10" maxlength="1500"></textarea>
        <p>*Please fill out every field</p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" onclick="submitForm()">

        <script>
            function submitForm() {
            document.contact-form.submit();
            document.contact-form.reset();
            }
        </script>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: AFAIK, your `<form>` is being submitted. Which means that your browser will navigate to a different page and further actions in your current page won't make much sense. Or, am I missing something?

Comment: @Alexander How do you know it's being fully submitted? We don't see any handlers for the `onsubmit` event, but they could easily be there. The handler could stop the submission based on whatever condition. I don't agree clearing the form would be the best idea, but it's up to the OP

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Your form is being submitted already as your button is type `submit`.  Which in most browsers would result in a form submission and loading of the server response rather than executing javascript on the page.

Change the type of the submit button to a `button`.  Also, as this button is given the id `submit`, it will cause a conflict with Javascript's submit function.  Change the id of this button.  Try something like

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="btnsubmit" onclick="submitForm()">
```

Another issue in this instance is that the name of the form contains a `-` dash.  However, Javascript translates `-` as a minus.

You will need to either use array based notation or use `document.getElementById()` / `document.getElementsByName()`. The `getElementById()` function returns the element instance directly as Id is unique (but it requires an Id to be set).  The `getElementsByName()` returns an array of values that have the same name.  In this instance as we have not set an id, we can use the `getElementsByName` with index 0.

Try the following

```
function submitForm() {
   // Get the first form with the name
   // Usually the form name is not repeated
   // but duplicate names are possible in HTML
   // Therefore to work around the issue, enforce the correct index
   var frm = document.getElementsByName('contact-form')[0];
   frm.submit(); // Submit the form
   frm.reset();  // Reset all form data
   return false; // Prevent page refresh
}
```

Answer (score 14):

since you are using `jquery` library, i would advise you utilize the `reset()` method.

Firstly, add an id attribute to the form tag

```
<form id='myForm'>
```

Then on completion, clear your input fields as:

```
$('#myForm')[0].reset();
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `HTMLFormElement.prototype.reset` according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset)

```
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```

Comment: In addition to mentioning the reference of your answer, it is more appropriate to include part of your answer. This could be useful for future readers in case the reference is no longer available.

Comment: I added the code snippet and linked to MDN. Never link to W3Schools and certainly never use it as a reference. It's a non-authoritative and sometime poor quality resource and isn't endorsed by or affiliated with W3C.  Always use MDN

Answer (score 6):

You can assign to the `onsubmit` property:

```js
document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = e => {
   e.target.submit();
   e.target.reset();
   return false;
};
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onsubmit

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
function submitForm() {
  $('form[name="contact-form"]').submit();
  $('input[type="text"], textarea').val('');
}
```

This script needs jquery to be added on the page.

Comment: jquery is good to have anyways.... Also @Jai would this not clear all input elements, and not bind only to the those in the current form?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to set the value of the form element. If you're using jQuery (which I would highly recommend) you can do this easily with

```
$('#element-id').val('')
```

For all input elements in the form this may work (i've never tried it)

```
$('#form-id').children('input').val('')
```

Note that .children will only find input elements one level down. If you need to find grandchildren or such .find() should work.

There may be a better way however this should work for you.

Comment: This will mess up the submit button's text because you just use `'input'`

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#contact-form input[type="text"]').val('');
$('#contact-form textarea').val('');
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the following with jQuery:

```
$("#submitForm").val("");
```

where `submitForm` is the id for the input element in the html. I ran it AFTER my function to extract the value from the input field. That extractValue function below:

```
function extractValue() {
    var value = $("#submitForm").val().trim();
    console.log(value);
};
```

Also don't forget to include `preventDefault();` method to stop the submit type form from refreshing your page!

Answer (score 1):

Just include this line at the end of function:

```
document.getElementById("btnsubmit").value = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var btnClear = document.querySelector('button');
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
 
btnClear.addEventListener('click', () => {
    inputs.forEach(input =>  input.value = '');
});
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```js
btnSave.addEventListener("click", () => {
  inputs.forEach((input) => (input.value = ""));
});
```

**Use the  button you want to clear the inputs after clicking on it  instead of the btnSave **

Answer (score 0):

On the function, you are running upon the event of the submit button. If you are using the form itself to run any if statements then do the following inside the function for the event.

```
//assigned form id value to a variable. 
let myFormId = $('form').attr('id');
//if statement or loop goes here.
document.getElementById(myFormId).reset();
```