# CRUD Angular App

Tags: forms, angular

its a crud app i am inputting user info into a form and then saving it in an array and then rendering it into a table .I can add more rows with different user data . And i can delete a certain row from the table . I also have a edit button but i don't have no idea how to do that.

Register.html file

```html
<div class="container">

  <h2 class="page-header">Register</h2>
<form (ngSubmit)="onRegisterSubmit()" [formGroup] = "form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Full Name</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="fullname" formControlName="fullname" class="form-control" >

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username" formControlName="username" class="form-control" >
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="email" formControlName="email" class="form-control" >
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">
</form>

<br>
<br>

<table  border="2" class="table table-striped">
<tr>
  <th>Full Name</th>
  <th>Username</th>
  <th>Email</th>
  <th>Password</th>
  <th>Delete</th>
  <th>Edit</th>
</tr>
<div > </div>
<tr *ngFor="let user of userDetails">
  <td>{{user.username}}</td>
  <td>{{user.username}}</td>
  <td>{{user.email}}</td>
  <td>{{user.password}}</td>
  <td><button (click)="userDelete()">X</button></td>
  <td><button (click)="userEdit()">Edit</button></td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>
```

Register.ts file

```js
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  fullname : string;
  username : string;
  email : string;
  password : string;

  userDetails:Array<object>;
    constructor(
    private validateService: ValidateService,
  private flashMessage:FlashMessagesService) 
  { }

  form;

  ngOnInit() {
   this.userDetails=[];
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      fullname : new FormControl("", Validators.required),
      username : new FormControl("", Validators.required),
      email : new FormControl("", Validators.required),
      password : new FormControl("", Validators.required)

    });
  }

  onRegisterSubmit(){
    let user = {
      fullname : this.fullname ,
      username : this.username,
      email : this.email ,
      password : this.password
    }

     this.userDetails.push(user);


   if(!this.validateService.validateRegister(user)){
      this.flashMessage.show('Please fill in all fields', {cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 3000});
      return false;
    }


    // Validate Email
    if(!this.validateService.validateEmail(user.email)){
      this.flashMessage.show('Please use a valid email', {cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 3000});
      return false;
    }


  }
  userDelete(){
    this.userDetails.pop();
  }
userEdit(){
//No logic
}


}
```

Validation service file

```js
export class ValidateService {

  constructor() { }

  validateRegister(user){
    if(user.fullname == undefined || user.email == undefined || user.username == undefined || user.password == undefined){
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  validateEmail(email){
    const re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
  }
}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: what should i do to edit details saved through submitting form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hardcode new values is simple:

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of userDetails; index as i">
  <td>{{user.username}}</td>
  <td>{{user.username}}</td>
  <td>{{user.email}}</td>
  <td>{{user.password}}</td>
  <td><button (click)="userDelete()">X</button></td>
  <td><button (click)="userEdit(i)">Edit</button></td>
</tr>
    userEdit(i) {
     let editUser = this.userDetails[i];
     editUser = { fullname: 'Tadas Blynda', etc. } 
    }
```

But what you need is probably this:

```
<div>
<form (ngSubmit)="onRegisterSubmit()" [formGroup] = "form" [hidden]="clicked">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Full Name</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="fullname" formControlName="fullname" class="form-control" >

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username" formControlName="username" class="form-control" >
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="email" formControlName="email" class="form-control" >
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">
</form>
</div>

<div>
<form (ngSubmit)="onEditSubmit()" [formGroup] = "form" [hidden]="!clicked">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Full Name</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="fullname" formControlName="fullname" class="form-control"
    placeholder="userDetails[editIndex]?.fullname" >

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username" formControlName="username" class="form-control" >
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="email" formControlName="email" class="form-control" >
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">
</form>
</div>
<br>
<br>

<table  border="2" class="table table-striped">
<tr>
  <th>Full Name</th>
  <th>Username</th>
  <th>Email</th>
  <th>Password</th>
  <th>Delete</th>
  <th>Edit</th>
</tr>
<div > </div>
<tr *ngFor="let user of userDetails; index as i">
  <td>{{user.fullname}}</td>
  <td>{{user.username}}</td>
  <td>{{user.email}}</td>
  <td>{{user.password}}</td>
  <td><button (click)="userDelete()">X</button></td>
  <td><button (click)="clickEdit(i)">Edit</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And

```
export class AppComponent {

  fullname : string;
  username : string;
  email : string;
  password : string;

  clicked = false;

  userDetails:Array<object>;

  form;

  ngOnInit() {
   this.userDetails=[];
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      fullname : new FormControl("", Validators.required),
      username : new FormControl("", Validators.required),
      email : new FormControl("", Validators.required),
      password : new FormControl("", Validators.required)
    });
  }

  onRegisterSubmit(){
    let user = {
      fullname : this.fullname ,
      username : this.username,
      email : this.email ,
      password : this.password
    }
     this.userDetails.push(user);
   }

   editIndex = null;

  clickEdit(i){
    this.clicked = !this.clicked;
    this.editIndex = i;
  }

  onEditSubmit() {
    let editUser = {
      fullname : this.fullname ,
      username : this.username,
      email : this.email ,
      password : this.password
    }
    this.userDetails[this.editIndex] = editUser;
    this.clicked = !this.clicked;
  }
}
```

Let me know please, if any issues.

Comment: But couldn't find, yet, a way to clear input fields after object been edited

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589193/clearing-my-form-inputs-after-submission you can refer here for that but thats not really a problem for me right now.

Comment: And thank you your code works perfectly. This is what i was looking for.

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45366955/same-form-for-creating-and-editing-data-angular4