# Same form for creating and editing data Angular4

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

Here is a form with two way-binded input fields. The goal was to create the same form to edit and create data. That was accomplished, but I am pretty sure that there could be a better way to do this (like using AbstractControl features). I also miss one fix here - if `clickEdit()` being clicked need to update form values with that object which user wants to edit. Thanks for any help and especially explanations about `AbstractControl` and `NgModel`..

```
<div>
<form (ngSubmit)="clicked ? onEditSubmit($event) : onRegisterSubmit($event)" [formGroup] = "form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Full Name</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="fullname" formControlName="fullname" class="form-control" >

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username" formControlName="username" class="form-control" >
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="email" formControlName="email" class="form-control" >
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!form.valid"> Submit </button>
</form>
</div>

<br>
<br>

<table  border="2" class="table table-striped">
<tr>
  <th>Full Name</th>
  <th>Username</th>
  <th>Email</th>
  <th>Password</th>
  <th>Delete</th>
  <th>Edit</th>
</tr>
<div > </div>
<tr *ngFor="let user of userDetails; index as i">
  <td>{{user.fullname}}</td>
  <td>{{user.username}}</td>
  <td>{{user.email}}</td>
  <td>{{user.password}}</td>
  <td><button (click)="userDelete()">X</button></td>
  <td><button (click)="clickEdit(i)">Edit</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { initializeApp, database } from 'firebase';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {

  fullname : string;
  username : string;
  email : string;
  password : string;

  clicked = false;

  userDetails:Array<object>;

  form;

  ngOnInit() {
   this.userDetails=[];
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      fullname : new FormControl("", Validators.required),
      username : new FormControl("", Validators.required),
      email : new FormControl("", Validators.required),
      password : new FormControl("", Validators.required)
    });
  }

  onRegisterSubmit(e){
    let user = {
      fullname : this.fullname ,
      username : this.username,
      email : this.email ,
      password : this.password
    }
     this.userDetails.push(user);
     this.clearInputFields(e);
   }

   editIndex = null;

  clickEdit(i){
    this.clicked = !this.clicked;
    this.editIndex = i;
  }

  onEditSubmit(e) {
    let editUser = {
      fullname : this.fullname ,
      username : this.username,
      email : this.email ,
      password : this.password
    }
    this.userDetails[this.editIndex] = editUser;
    this.clearInputFields(e);  
    this.clicked = !this.clicked;  
  }

  clearInputFields(e){
   let all = e.target.querySelectorAll('input');
    Object.keys(all).forEach(key => {
        console.log(all[key].value = '');   
    });    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would make quite a few changes to your form. `ngModel` is totally redundant here as you are using a reactive form. Utilize that instead and remove all ngModel's. The object you are getting from the form, is matching your `user`, so what you can do, is just push that value as is to the array.

So your template should look something like this (shortened, as the rest of code):

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="onRegisterSubmit(form)" [formGroup] = "form">
  <input type="text" formControlName="username" class="form-control" >
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">
</form>
```

In the build of the form I have in this case used a hidden field, that is also excluded from the form object as it is `disabled`. This is a helper for us, so we can differentiate if this is a new `user`, or if we are editing a `user`. The value holds the index of the `user` from your array. So if that value exists, we know to update the object in the array, if the value does not exist, let's push the user to the array.

This could be solved by numerous ways, but above is one option.

```ts
this.form = this.fb.group({
  index: [{value: null, disabled:true}]
  username : ['', Validators.required],
  email : ['', Validators.required],
});
```

So according to the above, we can modify the `onRegisterSubmit` to look like the following:

```ts
onRegisterSubmit(form) {
  // since field is disabled, we need to use 'getRawValue'
  let index = form.getRawValue().index
  if(index != null) {
    this.userDetails[index] = form.value
  } else {
    this.userDetails.push(form.value)      
  }
  this.form.reset() // reset form to empty
}
```

When we want to edit a user, we pass the index and the user in template

```html
<tr *ngFor="let user of userDetails; let i = index">
  <td>{{user.username}}</td>
  <td>{{user.email}}</td>
  <td><button (click)="userEdit(user, i)">Edit</button></td>
</tr>
```

And then we use `setValue` (or `patchValue`) to enter the fields with the existing values:

```ts
userEdit(user, i) {
  this.form.setValue({
    index: i,
    username: user.username,
    email: user.email
  })
}
```

That should do it! So now we can see how much we could simplify your code and get rid of some unnecessary things! :)

Comment: Many thanks for detailed answer. I didn't made this form from scratch, I just implemented some features and yes, I also thought ngModel was not needed here. But your answer looks great, I will explore it in details. Cheers!

Comment: Sure, let me know if you encounter any problems and I'm happy to help. I tested the code above, so it should definitely work :)

Comment: I got invalid error on form submit when i use setvalue. I am checking validity of fields using const validity = (!this.addForm.get(field).valid && this.addForm.get(field).touched) ||
            (this.addForm.get(field).untouched && this.formSubmitAttempt)

Answer (score 12):

## Dummy Forms

Creating Form that are reusable.

## Folder Structure

[image]

## Usage

**User Form Component**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submit(form)" [formGroup] = "form">
  <input type="text" formControlName="username" >
  <button type="submit"[disabled]="!form.valid"> Submit</button>
  <button type="button" (click)="cancel()"></button>
</form>
```

```
@Input() formData;
@Output() onSubmit = new EventEmitter();
@Output() onCancel = new EventEmitter();

ngOnInit(){
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      username : ['', Validators.required]
    });

    // Edit Mode will have formData.
    if(this.formData){
        this.form.patchValue(this.formData)
    }
}

submit(){
   if(this.form.valid){
       this.onSubmit.emit(this.form.value)
   }
}

cancel(){
  this.onCancel.emit();
}
```

**Add User  Component**

```
<user-form                  
    (onSubmit)="addUser($event)"  
    (onCancel)="cancel()">
</user-form>
```

```
addUser(data){
   // Call Http Service to save data
}

cancel(){
   // navigate to different route or something else
}
```

**Edit User  Component**

```
<user-form 
    [formData]="formData"                 
    (onSubmit)="updateUser($event)"  
    (onCancel)="cancel()">
</user-form>
```

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.formData = //fetch data from server 
}

updateUser(data){
   // Call Http Service to save data
}

cancel(){
   // navigate to different route or something else
}
```

**Pros**

1. Single Component for single use
2. Can reuse the dummy forms anywhere throughout the application.
3. Easy to maintain and extend the form

**Cons**

1. For each page you will have 3 components ( add, edit, form).

Comment: in user form will we have the submitted values through add form?

Comment: @sai User Form is a Dummy component. It will emit the formvaue using onSubmit. The add-form and edit-form component will use onSubmit emitted value.