# Same form for creating and editing data in Angular 6 using template driven from

Tags: angular, angular-material

There are 2 components. In `DashboardComponent` there is a list of created forms and in `CreateFormComponent`, I need to perform add and edit operation on the created forms that are being displayed in the `DashboardComponent`. Both the operations will use the same form.
I can navigate from the `DashboardComponent` to the `CreateFormComponent` according to a particular ID  but not able to perform the edit operation on it. 
Code:
dashboard.html

```
<tr 
  *ngFor="let user of users" 
  style="text-align: center;">
  <button 
    mat-mini-fab 
    style="background: white !important;color:black !important;outline:none;" 
    [routerLink]="['/Create_form',user.id]">
        <!--<i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>-->
    Edit
  </button>
</tr>
```

Create_Form:

```
<form 
  #spfForm="ngForm" 
  (ngSubmit)="createspf(spfForm.value)" 
  ngNativeValidate>
  <mat-form-field style="margin-top:-6%;">
    <mat-select 
      [(ngModel)]="Priority" 
      name="Priority" 
      placeholder="Priority">
      <mat-option value="High">
        High
      </mat-option>
      <mat-option value="Medium">
        Medium
      </mat-option>
      <mat-option value="Low">
        Low
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Create_form.component.ts:

```
createspf(value) {
  this.userservice.spf(value).subscribe((res: Response) => [
    this.IsAdded = true,
    console.log(this.confirmationString)
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Consider creating a StackBlitz project.

Comment: Ok. Can you give me a rough idea to how to do it. I have seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45366955/same-form-for-creating-and-editing-data-angular4 but not understanding

Comment: It's pretty straightforward. Just go to https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular

In the dependencies menu, type the name of the dependency and press enter to add it.

Comment: I am not able to do on stackbiltz. Please can you just give me rough idea about it. How to use both create and update in 1 form?

Comment: You should use Angular's  FormBuilder   with   [formGroup]  &  [formControlName].  I too stucked in the same problem a few months back but using this gave the solution as required.

Comment: Can you tell  me how it can be done using reactive forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't really provide a StackBlitz and I'm not having the time to create a whole Form Stackblitz for you, here's what I suggest you do:

In your `CreateFormComponent`, when in the `ngOnInit()`, initialize a ReactiveForm, either using a `FormBuilder`, or by manually creating one using `FormGroup` and `FormControls`.

Also inject `ActivatedRoute` in this component and subscribe to `activatedRouterInstance`'s `params` `BehaviorSubject`. If there's any `id` coming in from there, get the details of the item by that id and populate the form that you creted by calling `setValue` or `patchValue` on it.

In case of Create, since there won't be any id in the params, the user will only see an empty form. But in case of edit, since the value of the form would be achieved, the user will see the form filled with the achieved data.

Hope that makes some sense and helps you out.