# Clear validators when editing data using the same form for creating and editing data (Angular5)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

This is a dup of [Same form for creating and editing data Angular4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45366955/same-form-for-creating-and-editing-data-angular4) but my question is how to clear the validator when I edit user?

Example form

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onRegisterSubmit(form)" [formGroup] = "form">
  <input type="text" formControlName="username" class="form-control" >
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Form validator (I check for unique user name)

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  index: [{value: null, disabled:true}]
  username : ['', [Validators.required, this.duplicateName]]
});
```

When I edit user the duplicateName func will run as if its a different user, any ideas how to tackle it?

Comment: This link will be helpfull: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/angular-5-reactive-forms-with-dynamic-formarray-and-simple-validation/

Comment: The link suggesting to use clearValidators() but that means I will have no validation when I edit the userName...