# Form input fields is cleared including submit value also

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I working with form validations I want to clear fields after submitting form its working fine but `<input type="submit" value="submit">`is also being clear but i want only input fields should be cleared. i tried with `reset();` also but without adding reset().In my code fields is cleared Here what I'm doing wrong.
Can anyone suggest me how I solve this problem?

Before submitting form
[image]

After submit form
[image]

```
var Validator = function(formObject) {
    this.form = $(formObject);
   var Elements = {
        text: {
            reg: /^[a-zA-Z]{2,20}$/,
            require : true,
            error: "Not a valid name.",
        },

        email: {
            reg: /^[a-z-0-9_+.-]+\@([a-z0-9-]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,7}$/i,
            error: "Not a valid e-mail address.",
        },
        phone: {
            reg: /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/,
            error: "Not a valid number.",
        },

        message: {
            reg: /^(?!\s*$).+/,
            error: "Message field cannot be empty.",
        },
        gender: {
          error: "gender is required",
        },
        selectOption: {
          error: "this field is required",
          required: true
      }
    };

    var handleError = function(element, message) {
        element.addClass('input-error');
        var $err_msg = element.parent('div');
        $err_msg.find('.error').remove();

        var error = $('<div class="error"></div>').text(message);
        error.appendTo($err_msg);
        console.log(element);


      element.on('keypress change', function() {
            $(error).fadeOut(1000, function() {
            console.log(element);
            element.removeClass('input-error');
            });
        });

    };

    this.validate = function() {
      var errorCount = 0;

      this.form.find("select").each(function(index, field){
         var type = $(field).data("validation");
            var validation = Elements[type];
          if($(field).val() == "") {
            errorCount++;                       
            handleError($(field), validation.error);
          }
      });

        this.form.find("input, textarea").each(function(index, field){
            var type = $(field).data("validation");
            var validation = Elements[type];
            if(validation !== undefined) {            
             var re = new RegExp(validation.reg);                
             if (validation){                   
                 if (!re.test($(field).val())){ 
                    errorCount++;                       
                    handleError($(field), validation.error);                    
                }
             }
         }
        })


    var radioList = $('input:radio');
    var radioNameList = new Array();
    var radioUniqueNameList = new Array();
    var notCompleted = 0;
    for(var i=0; i< radioList.length; i++){
      radioNameList.push(radioList[i].name);
    }
    radioUniqueNameList = jQuery.unique( radioNameList );
    console.log(radioUniqueNameList);
    for(var i=0; i< radioUniqueNameList.length; i++){
        var field = $('#' + radioUniqueNameList[i]);
        var type = field.data("validation");
           var validation = Elements[type];
        if($('input[name='+type+']:checked', '#test').val() == undefined) {
            errorCount++;   
            handleError($(field), validation.error);
        }
    }

    return errorCount == 0;
    };
};

$(function(){

    $('form#test').on('submit', function (e) {
      var NoErrors =  new Validator(this).validate();
     if(NoErrors == true) {
         $.ajax({
             url: this.action,
             type: this.method,
             data: $(this).serialize(),
             success: function() {
                 // AJAX request finished, handle the results and error msg
                $('.success_msg').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();         
                $('input , textarea').val('').removeClass('error');

             }
         });

     }
        return false;
    })
```

Comment: `$("input#someField").val("");` `$("input[name=someName]").val("");` `$(".someClass").val("");`. Basically you just set the value as empty.

Comment: @Martin yeah in my form fields are being cleared but submit is also clearing.see in images

Comment: You can put a class on input submit and then use $("input:not(.uniqueClass) , textArea")

Comment: @Husna can you provide the html as well? I am curious as to how your button look like, because you're most likely targeting it somehow. Is your button somehow a modified `<input>` element by any chance? I am asking, because some CSS frameworks use input fields with a specific type, and or, class to make it a certain button, so maybe that could be why. In your code, you are targeting *ALL* input elements for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this based on your form input elements:

```
$('input[type="text"], textarea').val('');
```

Credit & References : [Clearing my form inputs after submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589193/clearing-my-form-inputs-after-submission)

Comment: `$('input[type=text], input[type=number], input[type=email], textarea').val('').removeClass('error');` i  tried this its working fine.but here i have to add all input fields .Is there any other way to exclude only submit?

Comment: Did you tried $('input[type!="submit"], textarea').val('');` :p

Answer (score 1):

*Edit:* Judging by your edited question, providing visuals, and looking at your code, you could have targeted your button(s) by mistake. In your code, you are resetting *every* input element. Some CSS frameworks use the `<input>` element with a certain `type`, and or, `class` to create the button.

---

An easy way to clear input fields with jQuery is simply to set the value to an empty string. Examples:

*Reset, targeting id*

```
$("input#someField").val("");
```

*Reset, targeting name*

```
$("input[name=someName]").val("");
```

*Reset, targeting class*

```
$(".someClass").val("");
```

By targeting specific elements, you make sure that what you wish to be reset, becomes reset, and nothing else.

Examples with checkboxes:

*Resetting checkbox, targeting id*

```
$("#idOfCheckbox").attr('checked', false);
```

*Resetting checkbox, targeting name*

```
$("checkbox[name=nameOfCheckbox]").attr('checked', false);
```

*Resetting checkbox, targeting class*

```
$(".classOfCheckbox").attr('checked', false);
```

The same logic follows through with most elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a class on input submit and then use

```
  $("input:not(.uniqueClass) , textArea")
```

Comment: Makes more sense perhaps to use the attribute selector, than introducing a new class: `input:not([type=submit])`

Comment: @Ullas Hunka where I have to add this code. I tried after success not coming.

Comment: write class inside the input tag then use this code at success method or you can use resolution given by @CBroe which is also true.

Comment: @CBroe this works only when you have single submit on the page. In case of multiple, you do require to make it unique in the sense

Comment: @UllasHunka this is about _excluding_ submit buttons from being affected; it does not matter in that regard whether you have one or three dozen on your page.

Comment: @CBroe yes, for excluding you are absolutely accurate