# how can i use reset() function in input form?

Tags: javascript, html, css

when i submit any value, i want to reset textbox automatically. any suggestions how can i do that?
my code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<ul id="myList">
</ul>
<input type="text" id="myText" value="">
<button onclick="myFunction()">SUbmit</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.createElement("li");
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(myText.value);
  element.appendChild(textnode);
  var list = document.getElementById("myList");
  list.insertBefore(element, list.childNodes[0]);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `myText.value = ''` ?

Comment: Submit? I don't see a form

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clearing my form inputs after submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589193/clearing-my-form-inputs-after-submission)

Answer (score 1):

In your submit handler you just first to find that field. You can do that with `getElementById()`:

```
var myText = document.getElementById('myText')
```

And then, set it's value to an empty string with:

```
myText.value = '';
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<ul id="myList">
</ul>
<input type="text" id="myText" value="">
<button onclick="myFunction()">SUbmit</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var myText = document.getElementById('myText');
  var element = document.createElement("li");
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(myText.value);
  element.appendChild(textnode);
  var list = document.getElementById("myList");
  list.insertBefore(element, list.childNodes[0]);
  myText.value = '';
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```